# Hide String characters based on column in different table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've written two queries below with results that look similar to this:

table : `messages`

| message_body |
| --- |
| Are you going to get the items from Walmart? |
| I am going to get the items from Target. |
| I picked up the items from target. |
| I am getting a computer from walmart. |
| I am going grocery shopping at Whole Foods. |

table: `companies`

| company_name |
| --- |
| Walmart |
| Sprouts |
| Target |
| Whole Foods |

I need to hide the names of the companies that show up in the companies table

My desired results are a query like this

| message_body |
| --- |
| I got the items from ***? |
| I am going to get the items from ***. |
| I picked up the items from ***. |
| I am getting a computer from ***. |
| I am going grocery shopping at ***. |

Because the string values in `messages` can have punctuation I would need to remove all characters that are not alphanumeric to match properly with `companies`.

I am working in Snowsight, but I know MS server, so I can convert functions/procedures written in MS server to Snowflake. Unfortunately, I cannot do this in Python. Any ideas to get me going? Thanks

Comment: so this is a form of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72302004/43992

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH message_body(msg) as (
    select * from values
        ('Are you going to get the items from Walmart?'),
        ('I am going to get the items from Target.'),
        ('I picked up the items from target.'),
        ('I am getting a computer from walmart.'),
        ('I am going grocery shopping at Whole Foods.')
), company_name(name) as (
    select * from values
        ('Walmart'),
        ('Sprouts'),
        ('Target'),
        ('Whole Foods')
)
select 
    regexp_replace(m.msg, f.name, '***', 1, 1, 'i')
from message_body as m
left join company_name as f
    on m.msg ilike '%'||f.name||'%'
qualify row_number() over (partition by m.msg order by length(f.name) desc) = 1;
```

gives:

| REGEXP_REPLACE(M.MSG, F.NAME, '***', 1, 1, 'I') |
| --- |
| Are you going to get the items from ***? |
| I am getting a computer from ***. |
| I am going grocery shopping at ***. |
| I am going to get the items from ***. |
| I picked up the items from ***. |

Comment: @Simon Pilgram ... This is great ! `regexp_replace(m.msg, f.name, '***', 1, 0, 'i')` will replace all records in the string i.e. ' I went to Walmart today. I like Walmart.' => 'I went to *** today. I like ***' Although it seems that it will only replace one value at a time i.e. "I like Walmart and Target" => "I like *** and Target".. Any ideas to get it replace all occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

To replace all occurrences, please try below:

```
WITH message_body(msg) as (
    select * from values
        ('Are you going to get the items from Walmart?'),
        ('I am going to get the items from Target.'),
        ('I picked up the items from target.'),
        ('I am getting a computer from walmart.'),
        ('I am going grocery shopping at Whole Foods.'),
        ('Walmart & Sprouts & Target')
), 
company_name(name) as (
    select * from values
        ('Walmart'),
        ('Sprouts'),
        ('Target'),
        ('Whole Foods')
),
company_name_list(name) as (
    select 
        listagg(name, '|')
    from 
         company_name
)
select 
    regexp_replace(m.msg, l.name, '***', 1, 0, 'i') as masked_name
from message_body as m,
company_name_list as l;
```